# Can Gcc build a executable program?

Tags: android, c, linux, gcc

All, Forgive me I am familiar with the C program for the Android/Linux platform. Now I am trying to use the `Sourcery G++ Lite Edition
for ARM` to build my sample C program and deploy it to the Linux of the Android platform.
Below is the instructions what I follow.
So far it works fine. But I have something I didn't understand well. please review it . thanks.

The Source code is a hello world program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc,char * argv[])
{
  printf("Hello, Android!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

In the development machine command console. run the following commands line.

```
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc hello.c -static -o hellostatic
adb push hellostatic /data/test
adb shell
cd /data/test
.hellostatic

Hello, Android!
```

So here is my question.

Can gcc build a executable file from a c source code file? Seems It doesn't need link tool. Is it right? thanks.

Comment: Yes it does. Obviously your program is linked against something (which is glibc), you can get glibc version adding printf("Glibc version: %s\n", gnu_get_libc_version()); to your code. You need to include #include <gnu/libc-version.h>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can gcc build a executable file from a c source code file?

yes, of course.

> Seems It doesn't need link tool?

no, I extract the following sentences from gcc manual,
GCC is capable of preprocessing and compiling several
files either into several assembler input files, or into one assembler input file; then each
assembler input file produces an object file, and linking combines all the object files (those
newly compiled, and those specified as input) into an executable file.

At default gcc will do complie and link operation, unless you type particular options such like:

```
gcc -c file.c
```

this will just compile file.c to file.o
or:

```
gcc -o file file.c
```

this will complie file.c to file.o and also link it to make a executable file finally.

Answer (score 0):

Although yanchong had already gave the nice answer , I also found a good read from [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/compilingandlinking.html). I think it will help to understand the concepts of `Compile, Link and Build`. Thanks.